# Clear radio buttons before adding new set of radio buttons in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am making an android app in which radio buttons are to be created dynamically based on the requirement.
I used a loop to create them
The code is as follows

```
         RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answers);
for(int i=0;i<qnumber;i++)
        {
            pquestion.setText(qanda.get(i).question);
            anstemp=qanda.get(i).answers.get(i);//Storing the answer array

            for(int j=0;j<anstemp.length;j++)
            {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getBaseContext());
                radioButton.setText(anstemp[j]);
                radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
            }



        }
```

About the code
Different "i" values will give different number of radio buttons and radio button text
The problem I am facing is all of them continously created without clearing the previous created radio buttons
how to clear them before creating a new set of radio buttons
Here is a screen shot
[image: Screenshot]

I want to print only Yes,No,Niether
again clear the view and print next set of radio buttons after clearing the present radio buttons

Please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try calling `radioGroup.removeAllViews();`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. But it is clearing everything below. I defined couple of buttons below the group which disappeared :-)

Comment: Thanks once again. Its my mistake i added those buttons inside radio group :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print only Yes, No, Neither then **why don't you declare it inside the XML layout directly.**

You just has to set the Question textview dynamically.

Comment: Some will have 4 options,or 3 options,or 2 options

Comment: Yes,No,Neither I meant only print the number of options for that question,not all of them i.e, clear the previous buttons and print new set of buttons